# Distribute data differently for an excel graph

Tags: excel, graph, excel-formula, vba

I'm having users enter data in an excel file, and if they choose a special option (see last column in the first step of the picture below) they should get a distribution of the same activity in a selected number of countries (see step 2 below).

My question is, can you create this kind of behaviour without having to use a macro, i.e. you can go from step 1 to step 3 without having to go through step 2? I would, if possible, like to avoid having an extra table and just draw the graph in a different way.

Thanks!

[image: Graph]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I completely understand your needs but how about a linked picture?

Put the graph, or graphs on a separate sheet (say sheet2 cell A1 and A2) and create a linked picture that has a formula along the lines of:

> If(SpecialOption="Yes",Sheet2!A1,Sheet2!A2)

This way the linked picture could even be a blank cell, so blank, unless your formula changes the link to where your graph is.